# Triggering on Account territory changes (ObjectTerritory2Association)?

Tags: trigger, account, territory

Has anyone figured out a reasonable solution to detecting in real-time when an Account's Territory or Territories (stored in ObjectTerritory2Association) has been changed?  We aren't allowed to create a trigger, workflow, process builder  off of ObjectTerritory2Association.  I want to keep up to date information in a couple fields at the Account level based upon its current Territory assignments.

Comment: I would create batch job which runs right after account affiliation update process and make sure picksup changed records to re-calculate sharing